# Resources to compare AIX compiler to Linux compiler for C++

Tags: linux, compiling, aix

I have been looking at this site https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_12.1.0/com.ibm.xlc121.aix.doc/compiler_ref/rucmpopt.html to check AIX compiler reference since I will transfer c++ files to Linux hp.  Is there are another source that I can compare those command-line syntax such as -q64, -qbitfields, -qstrict, -qarch ... ?

Comment: I guess `-q64` is `-m64` (`-maix64` on AIX) and `-qstrict` could be replaced `-Wall -W -Werror`